# Ruby prime number sum

Tags: ruby

I am trying to take the sum of the n first prime numbers. I found a way of showing the first 100, but I don't know how to get rid of 1 and how to make a sum with the numbers. I was thinking about storing them into an array, but I can not figure it out.

```
num = 1
last = 100

while (num <= last)
  condition = true
  x = 2
  while (x <= num / 2)
    if (num % x == 0)
      condition = false
      break
    end 
    x = x + 1  
  end
  primes = [] # Here

  if condition     
    puts num.to_s
    primes << num.to_s  # Here
  end
  num = num + 1
end

puts primes.inject(:+) # Here
```

Based on what I understood from what you guys are saying I added these lines (the ones commented `# Here`). It still does not print the sum of them. What I meant with getting rid of 1 is that I know that 1 is not considered a prime number, and I do not get how to make it without 1. Thank you very much guys for your time and answers, and please understand that I am just starting to study this.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Hint: in your `if condition` (not the best name, btw), you have a prime number. So, along with printing the prime number, also add it to an accumulator variable (the sum that you'll progressively calculate). After the loop you can print the ready sum (adjusted to exclude 1, if needed)

Comment: Also, you're reinitializing your `primes` array on each iteration

Comment: Thank you for the advice. You are right my post looks bad :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a list of numbers together you can use the following:

```
list_of_prime_numbers.inject(0) {|total,prime| total + prime}
```

This will take the list of numbers, and add them one by one to an accumulator (`total`) that was injected into the loop (`.inject(0)`), add it to the current number (`prime`) and then return the total which then becomes the value of `total` in the next iteration.

I'm not quite sure what you mean by:

> I don't know how to get rid of 1

but if you mean to not use the first number (which is 1 in a list of primes starting from 0)

then you could do:

```
list_of_prime_numbers[1...list_of_prime_numbers.length].
  inject(0) {|total,prime| total + prime}
```

Which would only get all the numbers except the first up to but not including the length of the array

and as for getting the number into the array you could push it into the array like so:

```
list_of_prime_numbers << prime_number
```

Comment: your first line can be simplified to `list_of_prime_numbers.inject(:+)`. And your second one to `list_of_prime_numbers.drop(1).inject(:+)`. JFYI :)

Comment: I always forget the first and didn't know about drop but I thought it would be easier for a person new to ruby to see how inject works rather than through something magical like using a symbol to proc. Also, drop actually creates a new array which isn't the most efficient way to do it if you care about such things, if you don't or it's not that important then hey, go nuts.

Comment: yeah, true that. I fear that even the full inject form is too much for the OP at the moment. Seems to me that they're in a "procedural" mode, writing code like they would in basic or pascal.

Comment: "drop actually creates a new array" - what do you think your slice does? Also, there are lazy enumerators.

Comment: Really? I thought it just pointed to that part of the array but didn't actually create a new array. This is why I like coding, learn something new all the time, even simple things like this.

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of `Prime` Enumerable in ruby

```
require 'prime'

((1..100).select { |number| Prime.prime?(number) }).inject(:+)

OR

Prime.each(100).inject(:+)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Prime IS an enumerable, but here you're not using it as one.

Comment: `Prime.each(100).sum`

Comment: @steenslag I guess this will work  `Prime.each(100).inject(:+)`

Comment: Recent Ruby versions have #sum: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum

Comment: `Prime.entries(10)` too which returns an array, instead of an enumerator.

Comment: well yeah, I just checked it out. Thanks for the info
Good that it has #sum now. 
In this case, it depends on the version of ruby which the questioner is using.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 Thanks for giving a more solution.
I guess there may b multiple answers to this.
Main idea was letting the questioner have some idea about `Prime`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev if we are being particular `Prime` *is a* `Class`. `Prime` is enumerable (meaning defines each and includes the `Enumerable` module) but is not an `Enumerator`. The `Enumerator` behind the `Prime` class by default actually uses the Sieve of Eratosthenes as its prime number generator and the actual enumeration is handled by `Prime::PseudoPrimeGenerator#each` which defers `next` to the actual generator. Other options include `Generator23` a brute force generator and `TrialDivision`

Comment: @engineersmnky: yep, that is (roughly) what I said :)